# Peewee uses 0 for non valid integer, when using IntegerField(), but I would like it to be set as NULL

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I have a attribute in my `orders` table called `subscription_id`, that need to be an integer. I'm using MySQL 5.7.
I'm defining this attribute in peewee as IntegerField().
But the problem is that some values of `subscription_id` are `''`, not a number like `200`, `23045` etc.

Here is my class:

```
import peewee as pw


# defining base model
class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

# defining my class for orders table
class Orders(BaseModel):
    subscription_id = pw.IntegerField()
    customer_id = pw.IntegerField()    
    status = pw.TextField()
```

When doing an `INSERT` in the MySQL table, using `tb_orders.insert(orders).execute()`, when `subscription_id` = `''`, in the MySQL table it appears as `0`, but I would like it to be `NULL`.
How can I do this?

I tried to set a default value, like:

```
class Orders(BaseModel):
    subscription_id = pw.IntegerField(default=None)
    customer_id = pw.IntegerField()    
    status = pw.TextField()
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. First I convert everyone that is `''` to `None`:

```
for x in orders_ok:
    if x['subscription_id'] == '':
        x['subscription_id'] = None
```

After this, I set `null=True` in the IntegerField():

```
# defining my class for orders table
class Orders(BaseModel):
    subscription_id = pw.IntegerField(null=True)
    customer_id = pw.IntegerField()    
    status = pw.TextField()
```

Now the `NULL` is appearing into the MySQL `subscription_id` attribute, not `0`.